# How to normalize a range [a,b] to [c,d] where a maps to d, and b maps to c

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

For example, i have a range of distances from [0,15] and i need to map them to the opacity of elements from [0,1] .

The element with distance 0 should have opacity 1 and element with distance 15 should have opacity 0.

I tried normal min-max normalization which maps 0 to 0 and 15 to 1 , but i need the opposite.

Formula which i use for regular normalization :

**`( (currentValue - min)/ (max - min) ) * (newMax - newMin) + newMin`**

Comment: What language are you using ? Pure CSS can't deal with algorithms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yeah it is a math problem, but it might have some particular implementation in javascript/angular or somebody might have faced a similar problem in programming. I have also added the formula , which is almost exactly the code i am using in javascript

Comment: What 's wrong with your formula?

Comment: @PhamTrung it will map 0 to 0 and 15 to 1, i am looking for 15 to 0 and 0 to 1

Answer (score 2):

The formula should be:

```
newMax - ((currentValue - min)/ (max - min)) * (newMax - newMin)
```

`((currentValue - min)/ (max - min)) * (newMax - newMin)` calculate the new distance from the root to the current value, and as the root of the new range is put at `newMax`, so, we get our formula.

Answer (score 0):

(( (currentValue - min)/ (max - min) ) * (**newMin - newMax**) + **newMax** )

Should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You should `.reverse()` your range array first. And from there it's just matching the boundaries of the two arrays. Possibly like so:

```
var distances =  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var opacity = {min: 0, max: 1};

var result = [];

distances.reverse().forEach(function(distance){
  var step = opacity.min+((opacity.max-opacity.min)/distances.length);
  var item = {
    distance: distance,
    opacity: opacity.min+distance*step
  }
  result.push(item);
});

console.log(result);
```